# Perspective to equip MathStackExchange resources to the creation of diagrams such as in LaTeX

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

There are some perspective to equip  MathStackExchange resources to the creation of diagrams such as the packages TikZ LaTeX? This is a viable possibility in the future?

Comment: If you mean adding Tikz support to MathJax, that's a decision up to MathJax developers, not to Math.SE. If you mean adding a separate diagram-creation tool, that's [not likely to happen](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9495/75064).

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram/9385#9385) and the comments to [that](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/mathjax-2-2-beta/9401#comment34248_9401).

Comment: Since the `\begin{picture}...\end{picture}` environmental is not supported (see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2727/752) question), I don't expect the `TikZ` to be in the near future. And creating a diagram in `TikZ` from scratch takes too long.

Comment: I usually use `tikzcd` for that.

Comment: Bumping this, for future reference. In the case of commutative diagrams, you can always use a permalink to a diagram you made in [tikzcd-editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/).